# Is it professional to specify the end date of the current occupation if it can be determined now?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I'm on an academic job with a possible end date a few months from now. So, in case I don't find a suitable job, I will extend my contract.
I wonder if it is common or expected to mention that end date in the "work experience" section? Or by doing that I'd look like I desperately search for a job as a negative point?

Comment: Are you in a country with notice periods? Then you will give your earliest start date anyway, no need to be redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say in the title

> *[...] if it is already determined?*

but then you also say

> *[...] with a **possible** end date a few months from now. So, in case I don't find a suitable job, **I will extend my contract**. [...]*

So, it's **not** confirmed. Actually it never is, until you clear the exit interview and complete the leaving formalities. Till then, it's a *plan*, and plans change! In case you put a date for whatever reason under the Sun the dates change, it'll appear very professional of you to mention that date in first place.

No need to put *any* information which is not required and might be changed. Just mention your last job tenure to "till date" in your CV / Resume / Application, and we're good.

Answer (score 2):

No it’s not especially professional.  For several reasons.  For starters, you are disclosing the details of your contract without a good reason, presumably you aren’t violating any NDA when doing so, but such contracts are generally considered at least somewhat private.  It’s also irrelevant, and including irrelevant information isn’t professional.

It’s not that you can’t disclose it if asked, but let them ask.

Comment: Being the person the contract pertains to, the OP is entirely free to disclose the end date of his contract. This might be private information for the person, but it usually isn't for the company. If they should disclose this is, of course, a different story, but this has nothing to with being professional or not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: as I said in my answer, I presume the OP is legally entitled to disclose the end date, it’s the should I’m addressing.

Answer (score 2):

> Or by doing that I'd look like I desperately search for a job as a negative point?

Do you know the saying? Always look for a job when you're still currently employed. That's because employers favor those candidates who are currently working. Also, this gives you more leverage when it comes to negotiating your salary and benefits.

Well, by putting an end date on your current job in advance, you're effectively shooting yourself in the foot and giving up those two advantages. Don't do it.